# Exclude a letter in Regex Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a Regex pattern for `<String>-<String>`. This is my current pattern:

`(\w+\-\w+)`.

The first String is not allowed to be "W". However, it can still contain "W"s if it's more than one letter long.

For example:
`W-80` -> invalid
`W42-80` -> valid

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Something like `(?:W\w+|[^W])\w*\-\w+`.  See https://regex101.com/r/5DHQoq/2 for explanation

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks. Is something wrong with `(?!W-)(\w+\-\w+)`? Someone posted this here earlier and removed it a minute later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your first string can be either: one character but not `W` or 2+ characters. Simple pattern to achieve that is:

```
([^W]|\w{2,})-\w+
```

But this pattern is not entirely correct, because now it allows any character for first part, but originally only `\w` characters were expected to be allowed. So correct pattern is:

```
([\w&&[^W]]|\w{2,})-\w+
```

Pattern `[\w&&[^W]]` means any character from `\w` character class except `W` character.

Comment: Thanks. Is something wrong with `(?!W-)(\w+\-\w+)`?

Comment: I think that `(?!W-)(\w+\-\w+)` looks simpler and it works on my test-cases, so I can't say that there's something obviously wrong with it. It's just uses a different approach, I guess

Comment: this regex allows leading non-word chars, eg `#$foo-bar` matches, but should not match

Comment: It depends how you're using an API. `Pattern.compile("([^W]|\\w{2,})-\\w+").matcher("#$foo-bar").matches()` returns false. If you're using `find()` instead of `matches()`, then you need to add `^` and `$` as prefix and suffix to match an entire input.

Comment: Thanks but why does `#Wfoo-bar` not match? It should accept the char ``#`

Comment: You used `\w` pattern in your question, so I assumed that you don't want characters like `#` and only want alphabetical characters. If you want to allow any characters, just use something like `([^W]|.{2,})-.+`

Answer (score 1):

Just restrict the last char to "any word char except 'W'".

There are a couple of ways to do this:

Negative look-behind (easy to read):

```
^\w+(?<!W)-\w+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/OSNOsyVywCNEjF).

Negated intersection (trainwreck to read):

```
^\w*[\w&&[^W]]-\w+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Pyi8Q6lSOPgMdY).

——

The question has shifted. Here’s a new take:

```
^.+(?<!^W)-\w+
```

This allows anything as the first term except just "W".

Comment: Counterexample: `AW-80`

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean? AFAICT `AW-80` should not match, and doesn't match using my regex.

Comment: My reading of the question is that the first string is allowed to _end_ in "W", it just can't be _exactly_ "W" (and thus `AW-80` should match)

Comment: @Ryan no, the *last* char of the first term may **not** be W, but earlier chars may be any word char (including W). The edge case of the term being only 1 char implies it may not be W, but this is covered by "the last char may not be W".

Comment: That wasn't my reading of the question, but it's possible I misinterpreted it

Comment: Yeah, @RyanMentley is right. The first String can't be exactly `W` but it can still start or end with `W` if it's more than one character long.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake and that’s what my regex caters for (see linked demos)

Comment: @Bohemian Why is for "Wfoo-bar
#Wfoo-bar
fooW-bar
" only Wfoo-bar allowed? The first String can contain a "W" at any place as long as it is more than one character long. E. g. `W-234` is not allowed but `Wa-l` and `alW-f` should be allowed.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake your regex uses `\w` so naturally we all assumed that’s what you wanted - only word characters, but hash is not a word character.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake see addition to my answer that might be what you want.